# Why I cannot get monetized by Google? Are there unwritten rules?

Tags: google-adsense, blogger, google-adsense-policies

I've created a website for a month or so. It's a hobby website that I was thinking that I could monetize it.

The website is about stamps: https://introtostamps.blogspot.com/

I have **another blogger website that is being monetized** at the moment.

Currently this website has 17 posts, and a few comments, but Google Ads does not allow me to put advertising yet and I don't understand why. I've already checked the content policies, and everything seems to be ok.

It says that the website "Needs attention" and when I click for more information I get this:

[image]

My question is: The design of the website is fine, is mobile friendly as well, so what is the issue?

Thanks for any insight!

(FYI, *I think that this is the proper site to post this, if there is another SO site that this post should be instead, please tell me so I can act accordingly. Thanks.*)

Comment: As "unnecessarily difficult or frustrating" is hardly objectively verifyable, concentrate on the under construction and error message part.: -- Did you have some "under construction" page in the past? (The report may not be up to date and refer to a point in the past.) -- Did you check the server logs for any error entries (personal testing experience may look fine even with some behind-the-scene errors)? -- If all is fine, it may be worth trying to tick that confirmation checkbox and have them review (again)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google's rule is that a site must have "sufficient content" before it is approved for AdSense.  They enforce this rule as requiring about 50 pages of text with at least several hundred words on each page.

In most countries, sites must also have existed for six months and get a certain amount of traffic before Google will approve them for AdSense.   Google enforces this rule more in countries where it sees lots of applications with low quality websites.  In countries where they get mostly high quality applications, they tend not to enforce this rule.

These rules are, unfortunately, not clearly written in their policies.   Their content policies focus on what kinds of content are acceptable and which kinds are not. To be able to evaluate your site and ensure that it has the type of content appropriate for ads, they have introduced the "sufficient content" standards to approve applications.  For more information see [Why does AdSense require sufficient content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61554/why-does-adsense-require-sufficient-content)